# Alternative for 'XXX did not need to be mentioned'

Tags: phrase-requests

I am sure that there is something, but cannot recall what it is that I can put into a text that simplifies the clumsy "XXX did not need to be mentioned because it was already established practice."

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain the situation where you would be using this phrasing. Is it for a  formal, academic paper?  It is always awkward to mention something only to say that it need not be mentioned!

Answer (score 2):

"It goes without saying," perhaps?